# Difference between and meaning of VSS & VDDS

Tags: bga

I am working on a small project that involves BGA's. It has a section of VSS and VDDS pins. The device is an [AM437x Sitara](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/am4376.pdf).

My assumption is, VSS is + and VDDS is ground; would I be correct in thinking so?

Comment: You got it the wrong way around, but you should post a link to the datasheet if you want more information.

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/am4376.pdf

Comment: Pages 60,61 of the *Fine Manual* you linked are pretty clear: anything labeled VDDxxx is Power and anything labeled VSSxxx is Ground.

Comment: Please follow forum rules and do research before asking questions.

Comment: I did, other then the data sheet, I found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, TI generally uses VDD for lower-voltage core logic supplies and VDDS for higher-voltage analog and IO supplies. I'm not sure where the 'S' comes from.

VSS is always ground, at least in processors.